# ubuntu touch questions and active discussions

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

is anybody actively answering questions for ubuntu touch on here
and active chat im using XDA but only one person seems to be active on there
anybody know any good resources at all :)

wayne

Answer (score 0):

There are several support channels for Ubuntu Touch which include,

- [Mailing Lists](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/)
- [Google Plus Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/111350780270925540549)
- [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-touch)
- IRC Rooms on freenode

I have noticed a lot of activity on every one of them except for askubuntu. I would recommend asking a question on askubuntu and then linking it on the other support channels to get more attention. It could very well be that the other support channels are usually more personal and where you can start a discussion with other developers. While here on askubuntu it is more of a FAQ type.

As for general information about Ubuntu Touch, the best resource would be the [developer portal](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/) and [ubuntu homepage](http://www.ubuntu.com/).